# Solution of a complex equation

Tags: complex-numbers

Is the solution to this equation only a matter of using the quadratic formula or do I have to do something more?
My results:
$$x_1 = 1+i,\quad x_2 = 1-i$$

The equation:
$$ x^2 - 2x + 2 = 0. $$

Comment: If you have any doubts you may try to plug $x_1$ and $x_2$ into your equation to check whether they satisfy it.

Comment: If there only stays the term 2*i, is it equal to zero?

Comment: $2i\neq0$, anyway you must have made a mistake with your calculation, the two provided values (i.e. $x_1=1+i$ and $x_2=1-i$) do indeed satisfy the equation.

Comment: You are right I forgot to add the middle term of the binomial. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct that you can just plug this into the quadratic formula since the polynomial is of the degree two. Another approach that can help to see it also is by completing the square. By this I mean that we can say
$$x^2-2x+1=-1$$
i.e. we subtract $1$ from both sides, and by doing this we can now say that
$$(x-1)^2=-1$$
and therefore
$$x=1\pm \sqrt{-1}=1\pm i$$
Another good thing to keep in mind is that if you ever find a complex root to an equation, then **it's complex conjugate is also a root**, which is exactly what we see here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.